# Seg Fault when reading simple CSV file - C

Tags: c, csv, memory, segmentation-fault

I am reading a 2 columned csv file into an array of structs:

```
struct unused_s{
    char col1[MAX_ARG_LENGTH];
    char col2[MAX_ARG_LENGTH];
};

struct unused_s unused[MAX_USEABLE];
```

But I am getting a "`Segmentation fault: 11`" during execution. I have tried my best to debug this myself through reallocation of memory but I'm afraid my abilities are not up to the task. I have, however, pinpointed that the error is occuring somewhere in this section of code:

```
void readCSV(FILE *file){
    int i = 0;

    char line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];

    while (fgets(line, 1024, file))
    {
        char* tmp = strdup(line);
        strcpy(unused[i].col1, getunused(tmp, FIRST_COLUMN));
        strcpy(unused[i].col2, getunused(tmp, SECOND_COLUMN));
        free(tmp);
        i++;
    }

    fclose(file);

}

const char* getunused(char* line, int n)
{
    const char* tok;
    for (tok = strtok(line, ";");
            tok && *tok;
            tok = strtok(NULL, ";\n"))
    {
        if (!--n)
            return tok;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Any help solving this/pointing me in the right direction to solve this myself would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `getunused` can return NULL but you don't handle it. `strtok` modifies the source string, so calling strtok twice on the same string may not do what you think it does.

Comment: Presumably, you have `#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 1024` somewhere?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin yes I do!

Comment: @John3136 How would you recommend handling it? I did try using a conditional in the original call during my debugging but that didn't seem to do anything... Perhaps I did this incorrectly?

Comment: How about getting rid of `getunused` completely, and replacing your read loop with `while (fgets(line, 1024, file)) if (sscanf (line "%[^;] %[^;]", unused[i].col1, unused[i].col2) == 2) i++;`? (note, you should add a *field-width* modifier of `MAX_ARG_LENGTH-1` numerically to the `sscanf` *format-specifiers* -- but you didn't show the `#define`, so I couldn't guess at it...)

Comment: @GabrielVega I suspect that your second call to `getunused()` returns `NULL`because `strtok()` has modified the input string so you don't get the right number of values. You could test this by using `strdup()` inside `getunused()` to work on a copy of the passed string which would leave the original intact.

Comment: thank you both! @DavidC.Rankin my program is still behaving oddly. I am no longer getting a seg fault, but the program is now appears to only put the last `unused_s` from the csv into the first object of the array. Happy to rephrase question with full code if this will help? my #define for MAX_ARG_LENGTH is 50.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments by John3136, you are returning `NULL` from `getunused()`, e.g.

```
const char* getunused(char* line, int n)
{
    const char* tok;
    for (tok = strtok(line, ";");
            tok && *tok;
            tok = strtok(NULL, ";\n"))
    {
        if (!--n)
            return tok;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

From your calls to `strtok`, it appears you have an input file that will result in `tmp` similar to:

```
tmp = "somevalue; othervalue\n"
```

After your 1st call to `getunused()`, `strtok` will have replaced each delimiter in `tmp` with a *nul-character* in order to tokenize the string, so `tmp` will now contain:

```
tmp = "somevalue\0 othervalue\0"
```

When you call `getunused(tmp, SECOND_COLUMN)` (where `SECOND_COLUMN` is presumably `2`), `!--n` tests `false` and `NULL` is returned.

**Why Tokenize?**

Rarely will you need to *tokenize* fields from a `.csv` file (or in your case a *semi-colon* separated file) Why? That is the whole purpose of a *separated values* file -- so you can read the file as input using a formatted input function to separate the fields rather than tokenizing on delimiters. (which you can do -- it's just not generally necessary). In your case, if your .csv file format is as set out above, then you can eliminate `getunused` entirely and simply use `sscanf` to separate the input strings, e.g.

```
void readCSV (FILE *file) {
    int i = 0;

    while (fgets(line, 1024, file))
        if (sscanf (line "%49[^;] %49[^;\n]", unused[i].col1, unused[i].col2) == 2)
            i++;

    fclose(file);
}
```

(**note:** as in my comment, you should include the *field-width* modifier of `MAX_ARG_LENGTH-1` (the number) as part of your *format-specifier* -- as edited above after your last comment)

Also, if your second value is terminated by a `'\n'`, then drop the `';'` from the *character class*, e.g. `%49[^\n]` will do for the 2nd value.

Comment: Thank you! That last edit was a lifesaver - I was sitting here trying to figure out why it was still being read in so strangely until you added it! Very much appreciated

Comment: No problem, I should have caught that earlier, but generically just used another separator instead. By using `sscanf` and validating with `== 2`, you simplify the read process quite a bit. Good luck with your coding `:)`